# 0x80070490 Error when installing .Net 3.5 Framework and .net 2.0 within that

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

Hello my windows is version 11, I have tried going into Control Panel - Turn Windows Features on/off and when I try to install .net 3.5 from there it wont work the Download page for .net 3.5 https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=21

*Error Message -
Windows couldnt find required files to complete the Requested Changes, Make sure you have connected to the internet and try again.
Error Code: 0x80070490*

I run the installer as Admin and receive exactly the same notification as above.
I can not find a location for the full .net 3.5 installation

Are there any solutions for this?

i tried installing the .net 3.5 and any method I used the same error came up so I can not install the .net 3.5 that I require